# Changing an element styles given a string pattern in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What to change give an `active` class to a `li` depending of the route.

I have this routes:

`/profile/2`

`/profile/2/info`

`/profile/2/contact`

I have a menu

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <%= link_to 'Profile', profile_path(current_user), class: current_class_contains?('/profiles') %>
 </li>
 <li>
   <%= link_to 'Info', info_profile_path(current_user), class: current_class_contains?('/info') %>
 </li>
 <li>
   <%= link_to 'Contact', contact_profile_path(current_user), class: current_class_contains?('/contact') %>
 </li>
</ul>
```

In `application_helper`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_class_contains?(test_path)
    return "active" if request.path.match(test_path)
    ""
  end

  def current_class?(test_path)
    return "active" if request.path == test_path
    ""
  end
end
```

The problem that I got is that if I'm in `/profile/2/info` or `/profile/2/contact` the Profile `li` is also given the `active` class.

I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if the *end* of the string matches? Unrelated, but `request.path.match(test_path) ? 'active' : ''` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [current_page?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F), Something like following

```
return "active" if current_page? test_path
```

& calling

```
current_class_contains?(profile_path(current_user))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`current_page?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) to build a helper method like this:

```
def indicating_link_to(name, url)
  css_class = 'active' if current_page?(url)
  link_to(name, url, class: css_class)
end
```

And use that helper method like this in your view:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <%= indicating_link_to 'Profile', profile_path(current_user) %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= indicating_link_to 'Info', info_profile_path(current_user) %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= indicating_link_to 'Contact', contact_profile_path(current_user) %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And with the new [`class_names`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37918) method that will be introduced with Ruby on Rails 6.1 it will be even simpler:

```
def indicating_link_to(name, url)
  link_to(name, url, class: class_names(active: current_page?(url)))
end
```